# Reachability not returning correct state

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, reachability

I have encountered an issue where Apple's reachability class returns an incorrect connection status, for example, it will return a connection to wifi when there is no active internet at all.  It seems once the app gets into this state it can't get out unless you close it, or a new notification correctly triggers for the connection.

Has anyone had an issue like this?

Comment: It will return connection to WiFi if it is connected to a Wifi network, not necessarily with internet access.

Comment: When testing on the simulator, i shut off my wifi completely and it still returns connection to WiFi.  I have also had it return no connection, while connected to wifi.

Comment: You had the same problem on device? 'cause sometimes the simulator is not perfect..

Comment: I have seen this issue on devices yes, but i personally have not been able to reproduce them.  Its harder to shut off wifi so abruptly in my testing environment.  But i have seen the app get stuck in the 'offline' state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better solution I have found is to stopReachability and restart it before every connection.  This forces it to grab the actual state and has solved all the problems

Answer (score -1):

After some further investigation, Ive found that Apple Engineers recommend you don't use the reachability class they provide solely for detecting internet connections.  As it can be unreliable.

Clearly.

The best solution is to check for connections using an NSURL connection and update all view controllers with a notification on success.

the answer post is here

[Should I listen for reachability updates in each UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490578/should-i-listen-for-reachability-updates-in-each-uiviewcontroller#12490864)