# iOS Network Connection Failure Policy suggestions

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, alamofire, reachability

I'm looking for suggestions to the best way to handle network connection issues for an iPhone app (iOS9/Swift2/Xcode7), to give the best user experience since we know that mobile data networks are unreliable. I have my coding options in place but I'd like to know what's worked well for other experienced techs. There's lots of info out there but nothing I could find specific to a strategy to occur when there is a connection failure.

Here is my basic strategy dealing with failed connections I'd like to implement (along with questions):

1. App sends request to api.myserver.com and the request fails
2. Wait X second(s) and try request to api.myserver.com again (how many tries and at what time interval would you suggest?)
3. Try pinging some other server (i.e. google.com) to see if we can access a resource other than api.myserver.com
4. If we can successfully ping google.com then we know our internet is working, so we try once again to ping api.myserver.com
5. If this last ping fails then we alert the user that we can't communicate for some reason and to try again later

I'm using the philosophy outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490864/580419) recommended by an Apple tech, which in general means you always check the connection to your server first, using Reachability as a separate check to ensure phone hardware is available.

At any time during this process if Reachability is false then we would put our request in a queue to be tried again when the phone hardware connection was restored.

I think I've got a handle on the code involved, but looking for insights like "this is what worked for our app and gives a good user experience during connection issues...and was approved for use in the Apple app store...". I understand the concepts of trying/retrying connections in the case of failure and alerting the user (currently my code already does this successfully), but still not solid on a good policy to use for how many times should I try to reconnect and at what intervals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most of the apps I have worked on it was useful to define a couple of categories of requests which have different rules. For each category consider if retries are appropriate and how long you can really afford to wait before considering the request(s) a failure.

1. At the most sensitive are blocking requests, things which the user must allow to complete before they can proceed. Sign in, checkout, some editing actions, etc. For these it is often not worth retrying(1) and failures need to be communicated to the user immediately: if the device is offline let the user decide when to try again, if the request fails you've probably already made the user wait too long. Since failures tend to block the user they usually also need to be communicated prominently.
2. Less sensitive are usually use initiated but non-blocking actions: pull-to-refresh, loading details of a selected collection item, or performing a search. Your user might be waiting to see the results but is probably free to give up or navigate elsewhere in the app and check back later. Failures still need to be communicated so users can choose to try again or at least know to stop waiting but the notification of those failures can be less prominent. Here retries start to make sense. I usually start by trying to define a time limit from the user's perspective, how long will they wait before the app feels broken, and then let that be your limit for how long a request can wait for connectivity or make any number of retries in response to failed connections.
3. Even less sensitive are requests triggered only indirectly by your user; polling for updates, loading non-essential images, warming caches. These you might retry but the impact of failure is often so low that it may not matter.

Of all of those requests your retry policy really only impacts #2 so I would make sure you actually have requests of that type before worrying about it. Assuming those do actually apply to your app...

> Wait X second(s) and try request to api.myserver.com again (how many tries and at what time interval would you suggest?)

I would set some interval here (in the tens to hundreds of milliseconds depending on your normal api performance) to avoid an accidental flood of requests. I don't want to suggest a precise number when I don't have a solid justification for it.

My experience has been that optimizing this value is unlikely to make a perceptible difference to your users because requests often take hundreds of milliseconds to fail and users are only willing to wait for a few thousand milliseconds so making 1 or 5 or 10 requests in that time doesn't really change the final outcome. If you are able to set different expectations with your users then your results may vary.

> Try pinging some other server (i.e. google.com) to see if we can access a resource other than api.myserver.com
>   If we can successfully ping google.com then we know our internet is working, so we try once again to ping api.myserver.com

I would not assume that this is true nor do I think that making an extra request to a third party will help you make useful predictions about when to attempt to reach your own systems. This seems like extra work to build and maintain and likely to be a source of misleading results more than valuable information. In what scenario do you imagine this provides useful information to your app or its user?

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, hopefully it's still useful.

---

Disclaimer: my experience is biased toward apps with a fairly simple set of REST or RPC style network requests. If you're working on a problem which calls for streaming data, P2P connections, or some other scenario then don't start with these assumptions.

(1) One end note here because I see it as a source of failures so often: These requests should really be idempotent. Yes, even those POSTs creating new resources, checking out your cart, or whatever. When you cannot safely repeat a request you'll eventually see cases where the request completed but the client never got the acknowledgement so it looked like a failure. It's much easier to recover through a retry (automatic or user triggered) of the same request than to detect and recover from duplicate requests.

Answer (score 0):

For better network performance. In my application I use to ping Google server for before every API request if its reachable then I called my server API else no network alert.

If you are on wifi network then also you have to do the same, because wifi reachability only checks for wifi connectivity not for network access.