# UISearchBar, textDidChange events, MultipleNSUrlConnection, crashes on tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In y iPhone App.

For  search functionality. I am using UISearchBar and WebService call.

Whenever `UISearchBar` 'TextDidChange' happen the web service call happens.

Generally we are typing very fast, so there are many web service call happens, and I am using NSURLConnection, and I am loading table on Finished Loading.

eg, 
WebService Call for M
WebService Call for Mo
WebService Call for Mor

Here, the problem is one webservice is going to finish, in between another web service called. This makes chaos.

Here, I solved the problem with writing.

```
**[connectionSearch cancel];**   

        connectionSearch=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this code in `textDidChange` method for calling Webservice

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];  
[self webserviceCallMethod];
```

You can also call service like below after `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(webserviceCallMethod:) withObject:searchText afterDelay:0.3f]; // after delay can be an anything that helps.
```

Don't forget to remove all objects from your array, before you add objects to array again in response of your webservice. (Array that is used in cells of UITableView)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have also two different kind web servive calls, at a same time. So, will it work NSObject cancelPreviousRequest, Instead I have done something similar. See my answer.

Comment: okay, nice to know new ways. Just for your info apps with `NSURLConnection ` will not be approved by Apple anymore. 
Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37693532/5012384

Comment: It is supported, as mentioned in your link. See the first answer in your post. And thanks for sharing the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like,

```
  **[connectionSearch cancel];**   

  connectionSearch=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

So, whenever the same Search web service call happens, and if the call is not finished, call is cancelled and the new web service call happens.

Comment: It removes the chaos of my tableview reloaddata, which I call on connectionDidFinishLoading. Thanks