# App store IPV6 compatibility test

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipv6

I have submitted a app in app store and my metadata was rejected with the following comment
—————
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, we were unable to register a new account because the Save button was unresponsive. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
——————
My app deployment Target IOS 8.0

My test phone is iPhone 6 with IOS 8.2

As per apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

i have simulated the NAT64 local network on my mac and tested it. The app works ok.
IP address screenshots attached using Nat64 and without using Nat64

I am not using any ip address numbers in my app. I only access the php script like www.kottapa.com/xyz.php

I am testing this app from bangalore india

Please let me know what could be the Problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple

Comment: sorry i don't' use those apis

Comment: The screenshots are nice, but what we really need is the failing code.

Comment: Sorry i don't' have any further info. I will update as soon as i get further updates from app store review team

Comment: They said: "Specifically, we were unable to register a new account because the Save button was unresponsive." Surely, you know where this code is?

Comment: As i mentioned there is no problem with save button code with my iphone6 and IOS 8.2. I need to check the same with IOS 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to missing App Transport Security Settings (Allows Arbitrary Loads ) property in info.plist. Without this property IOS10 won't' allow http requests.
But IOS 8 device processes http requests without this property