# Required iPv6 compatibility - rejected by Apple iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, itunes, ipv6

I uploaded my app on itunes multiple  times and received the following message:

(
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 10.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, when we attempted to create a new account a loading indicator spun indefinitely.
)

Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.

Notes: I have used AFNetworking version 3.1.0 for call web services(support IPV6) and Apple Reachability(also support IPV6) without using hard coded Ip.

My question: the changes must be done on mobile side or server side?

Comment: When I Google `Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.` there seem to be loads of related Stack Overflow questions, are they all not helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [required iPv6 compatibility - iOS app rejected by apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple)

Comment: @Oduy Samarah Alzoubi You are using REST api or SOAP api?

Comment: i used REST api

Comment: i got the same issue with SOAP API After changing into REST my app got approved. Not done anything from app side

Comment: Really, it is very strange issue. previously I have build an app with same AFNetworking library and without any problem in uploading the application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience with IPv6 reaches, you're probably right. When you develop your app in Xcode using the latest SDK for iOS 10.2, you should be save with IPv6 compatibility on your app's side.

However, Unix (MacOS audios are a Unix derivative) takes the path or url from your app and will negotiate at the OS level with the other side you want to connect with. This usually runs over a DNS. So, your app and iOS will first request an IPv6 IP address from the DNS. When the DNS understands IPv6, which is not always guaranteed, but it usually does, it asks the other side for an IPv6 address. If the other side does not support IPv6, the operating system will request an IPv4 address and set up the connection.

Since Apple will hold you responsible for the entire chain of services delivered by your app, you must ensure the requested side also supports IPv6 via it is part of the your apps functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what does you mean  with  " the requested side"? do you mean  server side??

Comment: Yes, your app is the requesting side, requesting the connection. And the server is the requested side, being requested to make a connection.

Comment: That can be complicated. Please, check the apple developer site at this url. It should give you all the information. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

Comment: I don't know the site, but I just ran a test on my web site and it gave a good overview on the IPv6 readiness.