# IPv6 issue application Rejected many times

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our update has been rejected many times for ipv6 network connectivity issues. Our networking code has not changed between the previous release and this current release.

once i have just changed the testing credential which we gives apple for testing purpose and my application goes live.so now i am very much fed up with the things.because sometime apple accept and sometime its rejected.but he give the same reason due to ipv6 compatibility issue.

i have refer the apple documentation as well.any one can help me for this..

i have also search lots op link of stack overflow.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing right test credentials to Apple? Also make sure there is no connectivity issue with your backend server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPv6 App Store Rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection)

Comment: yes no issue from backend server even many time my application goes live and sometime its rejected...i have also test my application which i give to apple for them testing its working fine as well...

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection

Comment: hey please see my question i have issue that many time my application goes live if there is issue of ipv6 then its not goes live on single once...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about apple approval and contains no code

Comment: Do all http request using "AFNetworking" library. I also faced this issue. And now all is ok. use this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue previously.

Steps you need to take care:

1. No IP Address should be hard coded.

Example: `let api = 54.32.55.88` is invalid, use `let api = www.mydomain.com`

2. If you are using any Pods make sure they are compatible with IPv6.
3. Update the Reachability if you are using older.
4. Check your server configuration if its configured properly. Removing the AAAA if not valid for your configuration
5. If using AWS, AWS doesn't support IPv6, nor IPv6-only DNS through Route53.

Check some other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection/37821727#37821727).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I too faced this issue before many times. **Apple is now supporting only apps those are compatible with IPv6.**

First I tested my application as per their description. I tested on IPv6 but I didn't get any error as they said. So first complete debugging after connecting to IPv6. If you feel, it's working fine then do this.

I found out the IPVersion of my network through different websites. I took screenshots of the network I connected to on mobile and sent those screen shots to apple for review(saying it's a proof of connecting to IPv6).

Here below are the couple of sites that help you in finding out which version you are using.

[Test IPv6](http://ipv6test.google.com/)

[Google IPv6 test](http://ipv6test.google.com/)

Now **it's accepted**

Answer (score 0):

As of June 1st 2016, all apps submitted to apple must be ipv6 compatible. 
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a) is the link for the announcement.

Now this comes with a lot of caveat. Basically this would take time to implement and apple started rejecting apps since September end. Now new apps that was being submitted was caught first, but now slowly apple is checking for ipv6 compatibility in old apps that owners are updating too.

Basically what apple tests is they connect their test device into a ipv6 network(their ISP broadcasts ipv6 connectivity), now if your app has a backend server, it should support any device that hits that server with ipv6 connectivity.

You can check whether your backend server is ipv6 compatible from [here](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php). Just paste your backend URL in the following and you will be able to see if your backend supports any ping from an ipv6 network.
If it doesn't then you have to make your server ipv6 reachable.

Answer (score 0):

same issue was for me, if you are using Network Reachability class then update it from apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Now my app is live with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had same type of problem. I made an app which has a screen which only comes when a notification come so they(Apple team) could not able to check my app and giving me IPv6 issue then i told him about my app briefly that how my app works. So point only that tell him(apple team) about your app your problem can be solve.