# Performance: App Completeness (iOS) - App Rejected

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

[image]We are facing some weird issue from last couple of days and our app is rejected from apple 3-4 times because of this reason.
**"Thank you for your resubmission. We noticed that the previous issue has not been resolved. We are unable to proceed with the review of your app until this issue has been addressed"
Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.**
We have tested it hundreds times and everything works great with us on same devices. Is it something related to iPv6 ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but I think the problem is with your back end. You need to make your backend  ipv6 comparable.  May b this help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple

Comment: This one also help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637818/ipv6-app-store-rejection

Answer (score 0):

I have same experience. `IPv6 rejected`

**Step 1:**

Go to your project and check for all related `AF_INET` , IPv4

**Step 2:**

Replace them in `AF_INET6` as IPv6

**Step 3:**

submit those dummy changes version as new project to iTune app store (dont use it for real production just for to PASS test)

Once that confirms you that it PASS, then do those changes to your real production release.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Also test your code with [IPv6](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) only to make sure it does not crash.