# How to detect Internet connectivity in iOS?

Tags: ios, internet-connection

How can I detect Internet (*not* WiFi) connectivity on iOS? The reachability .h and .m files detect WiFi connectivity, but what about the scenarios where WiFi is on, but the modem's cable is unplugged? In those cases, WiFi is enabled, but there's no Internet connectivity.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11055897/767730

Comment: Is it really possible to plug in Modem's Network Cable in iPhone/iPad ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apple reachability, I have a small project in gitHub that is an example of Reachability usage, in my project the [MMReachabilityViewController](https://github.com/manuelemaggi/MMReachabilityViewController) it's a generic example, but you can change it and the Apple lib let you check the connection in 3 different way:

```
reachabilityForInternetConnection // generic

reachabilityForLocalWiFi // local wifi

reachabilityWithHostName // for apllication based on a specific host
```